# Jenkins Build off specific branches (jenkins git plugin)

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-build-flow

I am trying to use

```
<branches>
    <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>refs/heads/master</name>
    </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
</branches>
```

in my config.xml

Which means I am intending to build only commits of master, but apparently jenkins seems to build from commits to any other branches too. I am not sure what I am doing wrong to accomplish this. Any help is appreciated.

PS: Using the jenkins Git plugin

Comment: Can you check the 'Branches to build' subsection - this should tell you specifically what it is cloning, and you can change the branch name here if you wish.

Comment: I have seen the tags like this: `<name>origin/master</name>`

Answer (score 0):

You only need the branch name without the refs

```
<branches>
    <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>origin/master</name>
    </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
</branches>
```

Or for local branch:

```
<branches>
    <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>master</name>
    </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
</branches>
```